# Ubuntu on Compaq 6710s: Hangs, Freezes, Flickers after some use

Tags: 16.04

**My System:**

HP Compaq 6710s,
RAM: 2.5GB,
HDD: 1TB

**cpuinfo:**

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7100  @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa1
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3591.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7100  @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa1
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3591.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

**uname -a:**

```
Linux ml 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**df -h:**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           250M  7.8M  242M   4% /run
/dev/sda7        47G   28G   18G  62% /
tmpfs           1.3G  316K  1.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           250M   68K  250M   1% /run/user/1000
```

**My Problem:**

Initially after logging, the laptop works fine, but after some usage UBUNTU starts slowing down. Then all of a sudden the OS will stop working. This may happen in one of the following ways and it's completely random,

1. Applications crashes, restarting them wont work. Opening them from terminal shows **segmentation fault**. Note, this is not for a single application but for most of the application on the system. Like Firefox will crash, then restarting it wont work. If I then try Chrome, it will work for sometime then "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong" page keep showing.
2. Sometimes, 1 or 2 drivers will not work, like all of a sudden the WIFI will stop working with everything else working fine.
3. Sometimes, the whole OS GUI will flicker ON/OFF and I will have no choice but hard-restart the device.
4. The whole system will freeze, even switching to tty1 wont work.
5. Sometime I am shown to "Journal Recovery" screen, where mostly it does it job and I have to login again for a new sessions or a few times I even have to perform ***fsck*** on **/dev/sd6** manually.

I dont know whats causing this but previously I had booted Windows 7 on the laptop and even there after sometime the laptop will hang, show ["Blue Screen of Death"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) and I had to hard-restart the system.

I know this info may not be enough, but I am willing to provide any other info, it is either fixing this or buying a new laptop, which I dont want to right now, so please help me resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `top` say when this happens?

Comment: @Raphael I tried `top | grep cpu` to see if the crashing in the firefox was related somehow, the cpu usage was in bw 30-40

Comment: Don't `grep` in `top`. Also, top takes cpu usage into account by default. But if you also want to check memory then type `top` then `f` then scroll to `%MEM` then `s` and then `q`. Your processes will now arrange in descending order of memory usage.